# nested has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.5.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :frequency_bands
end
```

I want to get all the frequency_bands for a user. I know I can write a method def freq_bands for User but I would like to know if it is possible to have has_many freq_bands for a User. In this way I can chain the call.

What I would like to have is

```
class User < ActiveRecor::Base
   has_many :frequence_bands, :through => phones
end
```

I think it is possible to have nested has_many using this plugin http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through

However if possible I would like to avoid using another plugin and rely solely on rails.

Comment: Doesn't rails do this already?  It works exactly as you have described.  `has_many :frequency_bands, :through => :phones`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones
  has_many :frequence_bands, :through => :phones
end
```

Works just fine. You'd only need the nested has_many_through plugin if phones itself was also a has_many_through relationship, which it isn't in your example.

(Editor: And don't forget the ":" in front of the last attribute)

Comment: True, or if you wanted *another* level of depth.  Of course, too many levels isn't good for the app.  I've written a blog post that walks through how to do it: http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/ - use sparingly!

Comment: Still works in Rails 4. Note: If you are using a different name for the association, be sure to specify a :source. For example, `has_many :my_frequency_bands, through: :phones, source: :frequency_bands`

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3, use the [nested_has_many_through gem](https://github.com/romanvbabenko/nested_has_many_through), for 3.1 this is rumored to work natively.  (Haven't been able to try myself.)